# How to change Toolbar's title's textColor & Tab's title's textColor?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-xml

I'm developing a **material design** app & I want to change the **toolbar's title's `textColor`** & **tab's title's `textColor`**.

Please let me know how to do this?

Sorry for bad format of the question!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Comment: How to change color of overflow menu icon or the three dots which indicates options?

Comment: use this theme   `<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTheme.OverFlow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item>
</style>`

Comment: Is there any way to change the color of the icons coming up in the status bar? Like the wifi or battery icon?

Comment: use this `DrawableCompat.setTint(Drawable drawable, int tint)`

Comment: after using the theme for OverflowButtonStyle, it has disappeared! What should I do now?

Comment: in`<item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item> ` add icon of 3 dot in drawable folder and of colour which you want and give path in src: attribute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91938/discussion-between-hammad-nasir-and-amar-yadav).